# Displaying POP up menu only one time whenever user clicks other than homebutton

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

i created a popup menu in iframe

i want to open that popup menu one time whenever user clicks on remaining links in the navigation but not at home page

after filling that popup menu it must redirect to user clicked page...

i am not getting any idea please help me to write code

here i am pasting some code

please help anyone

> ```
>  <iframe id="" src="Enquiry Form3/enquiry-pages.aspx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="800"></iframe>`
> ```

above code is opening for each link for every time

but i want to get open only one time whenever user clicks other than home button

Comment: you can use ajax modal popup in side it you can put the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Is your popup in an iframe? Or is your iframe inside the popup. I wasnt clear on this.

Do you want the popup to appear before the page load or after.  You could put listeners on the nav links to display the popup. Then after your form is complete navigate to the desired page.

Im thinking something like this

```
 $('a.navLink').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault(); //this stops nav relocation
     //then show modal
 })
```

Then when u close popup there should be a close listener callback. Put your relocation reference there...

```
 document.location.href = someUrl.com
```

OR

Just display the modal on the page after navigation completes and close it.